# Change and blur not working on section tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

When I edit the contenteditble and click off, nothing is happening. The function it's posting to doesn't exist yet, so it should issue a 'failure' alert. I've used fairly similar code without any issues. I've tried both 'blur' and 'change'.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

HTML excerpt:

```
<h4><section id="title+job+150" contenteditable="true">Independent Contractor</section></h4>
```

jQuery excerpt:

```
$("section").blur(function() {

                    $.ajax({
                            type : 'POST',
                            url : '<?php echo site_url('resume/edit_resume_ajax'); ?>',
                            data: {
                                resume_id : '<?php echo $this->session->userdata('resume_id'); ?>',                             
                                section_value: $("section").val()
                            },
                            success : function(msg){
                            },
                            error: function(){
                            alert('failure');
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/dKTVU/  I suspect there's something else going on, perhaps your url really does exist?  Is your blur function properly closed off, is it in a DOM ready event?  Does your section element exist on initial DOM load?

Comment: Thx. That's a good point, it's loaded into an iframe dynamically after load. Since I'm selecting a tag I thought it would be detected no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: My previous solution does not take into account how to access the contents of an IFRAME.  I forgot that these target another document, and must be handled very differently than typical elements within the same document.  The most concise way to do it in jQuery is:

```
$("#resume_holder").contents().find("section").blur(function() {
   // blur handler here
});
```

Comment: Thx. This looks great but it didn't work out...however this works: `$(document.getElementById('resume_holder').contentWindow.document).blur(function() {`....not sure why?

Comment: Doh!  I was totally forgetting how iframes work.  They are targeting a different document, so of course my solution was off.  Yours makes sense, but I've updated my solution to hopefully give you a more concise solution that specifically targets the "section" element.  The "contentWindow", or "contents()" in jQuery, pulls in the iframe contents to manipulate.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works with keydown, not with blur -- but that's a separate issue related to contenteditable.